# Is the virtual method in a simple class really virtual?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a simple class, which has no derived types and no inheritance relations with other classes.

```
class A
{
    virtual void f() {}
}
```

I am wondering if the "virtual" method in fact is not really virtual, so the class is the same as

```
class A
{
    void f() {}
}
```

Comment: Define *"really virtual"*.

Answer (score 12):

YOU know there is no derived types. The COMPILER doesn't know that. Such types, if ever defined, would be defined at a later time after `A` is defined.

So, at the point wherever `A` is used, `f()` has to be treated as virtual UNLESS the compiler can *prove* otherwise, for example when calling `f()` on a statically-typed `A` object, eg:

```cpp
A a;
a.f();
```

In this context, the compiler can call `A::f()` statically, because it knows it can't possibly call anything else.

But when calling `f()` through an `A&` reference or an `A*` pointer instead, the compiler will have to use a virtual dispatch, since the compiler can't know exactly what type of object is being used at runtime.

Comment: *the compiler will have to use a virtual dispatch* Not necessary. Devirtualization can be applied. The perfect articles: https://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html

Comment: @S.M. that article agrees with and enforces my statements, not disagrees with them. In contexts where the compiler KNOWS a virtual call does not need a virtual dispatch, it can be optimized away. But when making a virtual call through a reference/pointer, virtual dispatch can't be optimized away.

Comment: @S.M. "*The front-end looks for calls of virtual methods **where it immediately knows that derived types are not allowed** and produce a direct call... Front-end also special case calls within the constructors and destructors **since it is the situation where type of this pointer is known**... Because it is not front-end's job to try hard to optimize across statement boundaries, **whenever you however use pointer or reference, the call will stay polymorphic**.*"

Comment: Please continue reading all 4 chapters. The final one is about speculative devirtualization performed by static analysis of the type inheritance graph.